# Why can't I establish SQL connection despite setting driver (JDBC) path?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, netbeans, server

I've been trying to connect my Java code to SQL for hours now, I've followed blogs, seen tutorials and I'm still for my own some stupidest mistake can't get it to work. I've even enabled the TCP/IP connection.

```
import com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection;

public class SQLTestClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String url;
   url = "jdbc:sqlserver:sqlsrv\\sqlexpress;database=sqlJavaTest";
   
   String username = "sa";
   String password = "pass";
   
   Connection con;
   
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  
    }
}
```

[image]

The error reads:
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=sqlJavaTest using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".)

Comment: You have a SQL server running on your local machine? Are you able to connect to it through the command line or another tool, e.g. [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)?

Comment: Try removing the port number

Comment: It's SQL Server Express? Is it even listening on tcp/1433? Open the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool and check the TCP/IP protocol settings in the Server Protocols category. From memory the Express edition installer picks a high-numbered port at random and additionally only listens on localhost [127.0.0.1]. If you make any changes here you will need to stop and start the SQL Server instance.